# Are there any issues with defining a custom hook inside of a component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, closures, react-hooks

I have a component that uses the same React hook multiple times, using a prop passed to the component inside of the hook. For this example, I'm using the `useCallback` hook with the `finish` prop, which is just another function to be called:

```
const Example1 = ({ finish }) => {
  const runA = useCallback(
    () => {
      console.log("running A");
      finish();
    },
    [finish]
  );
  const runB = useCallback(
    () => {
      console.log("running B");
      finish();
    },
    [finish]
  );

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <button onClick={runA}>A</button>
      <button onClick={runB}>B</button>
    </Fragment>
  );
};
```

I'd like to DRY this up a bit by defining my own custom hook. My first attempt defined the hook directly inside of the component:

```
const Example2 = ({ finish }) => {
  const useCustomHook = action =>
    useCallback(
      () => {
        action();
        finish();
      },
      [finish] // See note 1 below
    );

  const runA = useCustomHook(() => console.log("running A"));
  const runB = useCustomHook(() => console.log("running B"));

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <button onClick={runA}>A</button>
      <button onClick={runB}>B</button>
    </Fragment>
  );
};
```

> **1** — this dependency array should be `[action, finish]`. It's a mistake I made because I didn't have linting rules enabled when creating this example. I understand the importance of correctly specifying these.

[Full example on Codepen](https://codepen.io/shepmaster/pen/gVvGqj)

This appears to work, but the [examples for creating custom hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html) all place the hook at the top-level of the file. The hooks FAQ [are hooks slow because of creating functions in render?](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#are-hooks-slow-because-of-creating-functions-in-render) addresses the performance of creating functions, but the examples are functions passed *to* a hook.

Are there any functional issues to be aware of with *creating* a hook inside of a component? If that's acceptable in general, are there any specific issues with capturing a property of the component in the hook?

---

Some answers question why I don't want to place the hook outside the component. The primary reason is because I'm hoping to avoid the duplication and verbosity of such a solution, as shown by this quick demonstration:

```
const useTopLevelCustomHook = ({ finish, action }) =>
  useCallback(
    () => {
      action();
      finish();
    },
    [action, finish]
  );

const Example3 = ({ finish }) => {
  const runA = useTopLevelCustomHook({
    action: () => console.log("running A"),
    finish
  });
  const runB = useTopLevelCustomHook({
    action: () => console.log("running B"),
    finish
  });

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <button onClick={runA}>A</button>
      <button onClick={runB}>B</button>
    </Fragment>
  );
};
```

Some answers focus on the creation of the closures within the component, which was not my intent. In my original TypeScript app, I'm using Redux actions combined with a passed-in prop. The action creators are reasonably static, as they are imported:

```js
import React, { useCallback } from 'react';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';

import * as actions from './actions';

interface BuildMenuProps {
  close: () => void;
}

const BuildMenu: React.SFC<BuildMenuProps> = props => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const useDispatchAndClose = (action: () => void) => useCallback(
    () => {
      dispatch(action());
      props.close();
    },
    [action, props, dispatch]
  );

  const compile = useDispatchAndClose(actions.performCompile);
  const compileToAssembly = useDispatchAndClose(actions.performCompileToAssembly);
  const compileToLLVM = useDispatchAndClose(actions.performCompileToLLVM);
  const compileToMir = useDispatchAndClose(actions.performCompileToMir);
  const compileToWasm = useDispatchAndClose(actions.performCompileToNightlyWasm);
  const execute = useDispatchAndClose(actions.performExecute);
  const test = useDispatchAndClose(actions.performTest);

  // JSX that uses these callbacks
}
```

Contrast this to the hook outside the render function, which requires passing in `props.close`:

```js
const useDispatchAndClose = (action: () => void, close: () => void) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  return useCallback(
    () => {
      dispatch(action());
      close();
    },
    [action, close, dispatch]
  );
}

const BuildMenu: React.SFC<BuildMenuProps> = props => {
  const compile = useDispatchAndClose(actions.performCompile, props.close);
  const compileToAssembly = useDispatchAndClose(actions.performCompileToAssembly, props.close);
  const compileToLLVM = useDispatchAndClose(actions.performCompileToLLVM, props.close);
  const compileToMir = useDispatchAndClose(actions.performCompileToMir, props.close);
  const compileToWasm = useDispatchAndClose(actions.performCompileToNightlyWasm, props.close);
  const execute = useDispatchAndClose(actions.performExecute, props.close);
  const test = useDispatchAndClose(actions.performTest, props.close);

  // JSX that uses these callbacks
}
```

Comment: I guess `[action, props, dispatch]`  is not correct either: props itself is a new dictionary every time. So it won't work. It should be  `[action, close, dispatch]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see no problem with your approach. All of the hooks are still being called unconditionally in the same order with each render. React would have no way to tell the difference at runtime between how the code structure in `Example1` interacts with React APIs vs. `Example2`.

> This appears to work, but the examples for creating custom hooks all place the hook at the top-level of the file.

The custom hook examples in the documentation are showing how to create hooks that can be reused in multiple components. For that purpose, they need to be at the top-level. You have a different use case.

As to whether or not this is technically a "custom hook"? The React Hooks ESLint rules definitely consider it to be a custom hook, otherwise you would get a warning about calling hooks within a function that "is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook function" (for instance, if you rename `useCustomHook` to `usingCustomHook` you will get a warning). And the ESLint rules will enforce the [rules of hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html) on your custom hook. [Here is a sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/custom-hook-in-component-r8duv) where I have intentionally left out a dependency in the `useCallback` call and the missing dependency ('greetee') is reported by the ESLint rules.

My only caveat is that in the [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level) it does say:

> Don’t call Hooks inside loops, conditions, or nested functions.

Your custom hook could be considered a nested function. If this manner of defining custom hooks were determined in the future to be problematic for reasons I'm not seeing, you may have some risk of the ESLint rules later being changed/enhanced in a manner that complains about this.

> Are there any functional issues to be aware of with creating a hook inside of a component?

I don't see any way in which this manner of usage will function differently than the equivalent code with the hook defined at the top-level with additional arguments passed to it.

> If that's acceptable in general, are there any specific issues with capturing a property of the component in the hook?

The custom hook will be redefined with each render, so it won't "capture" a property of the component in any meaningful way that could change observable behavior so long as you only call it unconditionally in the same component in which it was defined. If you were to instead pass the custom hook as a property to another component which then calls it, I think that could be problematic (and this would be the sort of problematic usage pattern that could possibly lead to the ESLint rules being tightened to complain about what you're doing).

Comment: Thank you for being the first answer to address my direct question instead of solely concentrating on some of the minutia about what makes something a hook.

Comment: FYI -- I've also [pinged Dan Abramov](https://twitter.com/ryanecogswell/status/1163475827817877505) on this to see if he has any reasons why this should be discouraged. Don't know if he'll respond. He's fairly responsive to people's questions on Twitter, but he also gets pounded by a lot of them.

Comment: Thank you! It's a dangerous game you are playing, as Dan has a history of writing really good SO answers and might steal the checkmark from you... ;-)

Comment: I'm OK with that -- I'd rather have the information than the checkmark.

Answer (score 1):

I would not say it is a custom hook, you just wrapped hook to a callback. Although it looks like a hook and even called like a hook it is not a hook, because the main idea of custom hooks is extracting repeatable logic from the component in order to reduce complexity.

I guess you think too much about hooks.
Your example can be written so:

```
 const Example2 = ({ finish, depA, depB }) => {
  const executeAnAction = useCallback(
    action => {
      action();
      finish();
    },
    [finish]
  );

  const runA = useCallback(
    () => executeAnAction(() => console.log("running A", depA)),
    [depA, executeAnAction]
  );
  const runB = useCallback(
    () => executeAnAction(() => console.log("running B", depB)),
    [depB, executeAnAction]
  );

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <button onClick={runA}>A</button>
      <button onClick={runB}>B</button>
    </Fragment>
  );
};
```

Which is a little simpler.

The second reason: In your example custom hook makes keeping dependencies of hooks in actual state is a little more difficult. In fact `useCustomHook` should have `[finish, action]` dependency (because action can have their own dependencies) Plugins like [eslint-plugin-react-hooks](https://github.com/facebook/react/tree/master/packages/eslint-plugin-react-hooks) will warn you about it. Unfortunately  eslint-plugin-react-hooks will not be able evaluate dependencies of `action` in `useCustomHook`, but it will work fine in case of 2 simple `useCallback` like in my example

Here is [an article that highlights importance of correct dependencies of hooks](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/).

Comment: *it is not a hook* — do you have any references to bolster the claim that a function **must** be defined outside of the component to be a hook? *the main idea of custom hooks is extracting repeatable logic [...] in order to reduce complexity* — because this is the reason I'm doing it.

Comment: I do agree that the dependencies in my second example are incorrect, but I feel that also demonstrates *why* I want such functionality; with the custom hook, I can fix such problems in one place, as opposed to in multiple. *your example custom hook makes keeping dependencies of hooks in actual state is a little more difficult* — I don't see how it makes it **more** difficult; could you expand on that?

Comment: I don't see a direct answer to my question: *Are there any functional issues  with creating a hook inside of a component?*. I understand that you are making an argument that it's not a hook, but in that case, assume that I never said the word "hook" but just defined a little function and called it `doCustomThing` instead.

Comment: " I don't see how it makes it more difficult; could you expand on that? "  Ok, you have added `action` to dependencies, but you create a new `action` every re-render, so in other words, your cache will be invalidated every time and does not work at all.

Comment: To make it work you have to memoize `action` with `useMemo` or `useCallback` before passing to the `useTopLevelCustomHook`. It will make using `useTopLevelCustomHook` awkward.

Comment: And, well, you can always to give up on memoization and say "I don't care about performance".
But later you will probably want to use the same approach with "useEffect" and, shit, you run into running side effect every re-render.

Answer (score 0):

It's *JavaScript* so you can do *whatever you like*, but you should ask yourself if it makes any sense.

The only reason to keep a function in the component is if it requires access to the variables that are private to the component. If it's generic (a *pure function* they call it) and gets all the params to work on as arguments, it doesn't matter where you place it and since there are complications associated with its placement *inside* the component - why would you still consider doing it? I'd recommend put it *outside of the component*. It makes all the sense.

So that you understand the reasoning more clearly, by doing:

```
   const useCustomHook = action =>
    useCallback(
      () => {
        action();
        finish();
      },
      [finish]
    );
```

...you are still creating `useCustomHook` for every update. For `useCallback` to do it's job, it should be a wrapper to the function that you intend to create, like this:

```
    const useCustomHook = useCallback(action =>
      () => {
        action();
        finish();
      },
      [finish]
    );
```

The arrow functions that you pass to `useCustomHook` will be created for every update; doesn't that effectively negate all the shenanigans that you had to add there?

Simply put those functions *outside*, you *do not even need* to turn it into a custom hook.

Comment: I don't see a direct answer to my question: *Are there any functional issues  with creating a hook inside of a component?*. You seem to insinuate that there **are**: *since there are complications associated with its placement inside the component*, but you don't state what they are.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in other answers, this question isn't really about hooks, but whether or not creating functions inside functional components is ok.  The answer is yes, it's a perfectly acceptable pattern to create a function inside a functional component.  You just have to be aware that if performance issues do bubble up, you may have to do a bit of optimizing after the fact.  Wrapping your fairly static functions in `useCallback` is already doing a bit of that optimization already, so I wouldn't expect this code to become an issue.

Comment: Are you also stating that a hook inside of the component *isn't a hook*? If so, can you cite a resource to back up that claim?

Comment: I did not state that, I answered your question about performance of writing functions (hooks are functions) within functional components.

Comment: Yep, I thought that might be the case, which is why I wanted to double check.

Comment: However, my question is **not** about performance. In the question, I included the research I did (which links to the React FAQ about performance impacts of creating functions in render) and I stated (emphasis added): *Are there any **functional issues** to be aware of*.

Comment: What do you mean by functional issues?